# My code only fetches mp3 files from internal storage and not from SD card

Tags: java, android-studio, file, arraylist, android-external-storage

```
public ArrayList<File> fetchSongs(File file){
        ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList();
        File[] songs = file.listFiles();
        if (songs != null){
            for (File myFile: songs){
                if (myFile.isDirectory() && !myFile.isHidden()){
                    arrayList.addAll(fetchSongs(myFile));
                }else{
                    if (myFile.getName().endsWith(".mp3") && !myFile.getName().startsWith(".")){
                        arrayList.add(myFile);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return arrayList;
    }
```

I wrote this code for my music player to fetch all ".mp3" files from the storage but it doesn't fetch from SD card. Though it works fine with internal storage. Your help will be much appreciated. Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

Double check that you aren't being affected by mixed case names, try changing the test to lowercase name:

```
if (myFile.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".mp3") && // ...
```